# Jasper Report - Current Number of Group in Page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a PDF report split in several pages.
In every page I may have one or more groups. What I need is a count of current group number inside that page resetting at page change.
So the first group in page has 1, the next one 2 etc...
When I change a Page, the count has to restart from one.

I have found this good variable definition but it counts current group number for the entire report, ignoring the page.

```
<variable name="currentGroupNumber" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="GroupName">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[($V{GroupName_COUNT} == 1) ? $V{currentGroupNumber}+1 : $V{currentGroupNumber}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[1]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The variable is missing `resetType="Page"`

Also, the variable looks a little more complex than it should, something like the following might do:

```
<variable name="currentGroupNumber" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="GroupName" resetType="Page">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA["foo"]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but neither this solution works. Unfortunally Jasper has a big problem managing group with the option "keep togheter". When a group is moved to another page due to this flag, every counting or resetting function is calculate "before" the move so I have the group in a new page with the data like it was still in the previous.